# Check if a program exists in bash

Tags: bash, shell, solaris

I am trying to check if md5sum or digest exists on solaris and script is used on different machines.

Here is the function in sh script which is called from a ksh script

```
getMD5cmd ()
{
    PATH="${PATH}:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sfw/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin/bin"
    if type -p md5sum;then
        MD5CMD=`type -p md5sum`
    elif type -p digest;then
        MD5CMD="`type -p digest` -a md5"
    fi
    echo "HERE ${MD5CMD}"
}
```

When I run scripts I get

```
-p not found
md5sum not found
-p not found
digest is /bin/digest
HERE
```

However, when I type it in a terminal, works as exptected

Any Ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely running `ksh` or possibly Bash for your interactive shell. Both of these have a `-p` option for `type`. The shell (probably `sh`) that your script is running in has `type` but doesn't have the `-p` option so it's looking for "-p" as the name of an executable and it doesn't find it.

So you could change your script to use `ksh` or you could use the `which` program. The latter is probably more portable, since some systems don't have `ksh`.

Comment: I can't believe how naive I could get, never even spared a thought for that.

Thanks for shedding some light on that. I converted script to bash for now and my code works

Comment: oh well, I converted my script to be bash and ended up using your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

As you are setting the PATH, knowing where precisely the command is seems unnecessary.

```
getMD5cmd ()
{
    PATH=${PATH}:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sfw/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin/bin
    md5sum /dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 && MD5CMD=md5sum || MD5CMD="digest -a md5"
    echo "HERE ${MD5CMD}"
}
getMD5cmd
```

Comment: I am not interested in exact path.  This script sits on the users home/bin and depending on the machine the user logs on, I wan't to know which of the commands exists on the system.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following syntax:

```
MD5CMD="$(type -p md5sum digest |sed -e 's/digest$/digest -a md5/' |head -1)"
if [ -z "$MD5CMD" ]; then
    echo 'no md5 sum command found' >&2
    exit 1
fi
echo "HERE $MD5CMD"
```

I tried this in Cygwin and `type` will return multiple rows, so it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
if which md5sum >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    md5cmd="md5sum"
elif  which digest >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    md5cmd="digest -a md5"
else
    echo "No md5 command found" >&2
    exit 1
fi

$md5cmd YOUR_FILE
```

Comment: first condition evaluates to true even tough there is no md5sum on the machine

Comment: I think the reason for that is "which" always have an output on Solaris,  when command is not found the response is 
"no md5sum in /usr/bin /vol2/bin"